# Earliest Recorded Name in History?

Tags: ancient-history

Is there an agreed upon earliest recorded name in history? I'm guessing it would be a king, pharaoh, or other important person. By recorded I mean a name that is written somewhere like on a grave marker or something.

Comment: @YannisRizos Comments in that question mention that the earliest recorded name may be different than the earliest recorded person. It suggests Inanna (the name of a goddess) as the earliest recorded name.

Comment: @called2voyage ... however, the OQ himself seems to have assumed he was asking about a person's name.

Comment: @T.E.D. True, but just because they assume that a historical person's name would be the earliest doesn't mean that they wouldn't view an earlier name (that is not associated with a historical person) as a valid answer.

Comment: **"By recorded I mean a name that is written somewhere"**- does this not imply "earliest record" such as edict/cuneiform..whatever? Rather than the name itself, that is.

Comment: @Rajib Right, earlier recorded name, I meant.

Comment: impossible to answer. The recorded name might not yet have been found, it might not have been recognised as such, the recording might have been destroyed so it can never be found again...

Comment: @jwenting That's nitpicking. The implication is "earliest recorded name that we know of today".